# Issue with creation of reports, images and informations are missing

Tags: ms-access, office365

I'm trying to generate some reports on ms-access, at the beginning I thought my problem came from the size of my images but in fact that's not true. I'm generating some reports with different informations, different images, there is more or less pages depending on the report. And I encountered some issues with the reports with a lot of pages, at the beginning everything is correctly generated, but very quickly I saw missing informations, missing images until there are only blank pages. Maybe a processor issue during the creation of the pages, there is a way to fix that ?
Thanks in advance for your answer.

[Example of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGkUW.png)

Here is an example of my report, the white square represent my image, and the blue squares represents my informations about my product.

And in the following example, I have generated my report and at the beginning everything is fine (Page 1), after I've only the image of my product (Pages 2,3) until I got nothing (Page 4). In this example there is 88 pages in reality, I show you the part were there is a problem.

[Example with what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itkBl.png)

For my DB, she was created a long time ago with visual fox pro and for my query it's between 4 tables and the query returns more of 60 fields. I can't show you this, because this Access file was created by another user and I can't modify a lot of things, I can't have the request in SQL language, it's blocked.

And the last part, my images are stored in a local server, we're placing them in the report by looking the reference of the product.

I hope that this informations will be useful to answer me.

Comment: More details are needed, like query view/SQL of the underlying reports, images of the report

Comment: Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: Ok I've added more informations with photos, I hope it will be useful for you.